# C# winform - playing wav files from embedded resource

Tags: c#, winforms, wav

I have 15 1-second wav files, that need to play one every second, for 2 minutes.  Is it better to read the wav files into memory at application load and play from there, or load on the fly from Properties.Resources each second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this be something that potentially keep adding additional WAV files down the line? If not, i would strongly recommend loading them up into a memory container that you can spin off new threads for each execution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing it hybrid. Take a look, if it is in memory and if not (first time needed) load it into it (maybe with a `Dictionary<string, Stream>`) and use it from there. So you don't have a big load issue at the beginning and you only take these files into memory that really needed and not the maybe existing but not needed ones.